# JQuery variable sent with AJAX to PHP gets 'null' on var_dump();

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

As the title describes it, I cannot get the value from my JQuery variable into a PHP one.

My JQuery code is like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var mbscr = 0;

  function checkSize() {
    if ($("#orientation").css("width") == "200px") {
      var mbscr = 1
    } else { 
      var mbscr = 2 
    }

    $.ajax({
      type:"POST",
      url: './a/cmn.arr.php',
      data: { mbscr : mbscr },
      cache: false,
      success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
      }
    });
    return false;
  };

  checkSize(mbscr);

  $(window).resize(checkSize);
});
```

The PHP one is:

```
if(isset($_POST['mbscr']) && !empty($_POST['mbscr'])) {
    $_get_mbscr = $_POST['mbscr'];
}

var_dump($_get_mbscr);
```

If I use `alert()` instead of `console.log()`, the JQuery parts does its job, it alerts me what it should. My problem is I always get a null value for `var_dump()`, even when I do `var_dump($_POST['mbscr'])`.

Any help will be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Mb problem in than line '  url: './a/cmn.arr.php',' check withoud dot.

Comment: what happens when you put this url in your browser? ./a/cmn.arr.php

Comment: The path is not the problem, I've tried doing it in index.php, and I got the same thing.

Comment: What will return var_dump($_POST) ?

Comment: It shows array(0) { }

Comment: before `data:{ mbscr : mbscr}`  do `console.log(mbscr)` to inspect what is inside that variable

Comment: also inspect the network traffic to see if the problem is in the client code or in the server code (if the variable sent to the server as null , then the problem will be probably in the client code )

Comment: I get the value that i should, alert(data) does the same, after success.

Comment: I mean the data that you send to the server - in that line `data:{ mbscr : mbscr}` - not the data that is passed to the success function after success `success:function(data)`

Comment: What will happen if you send data manually?  data:  { mbscr:  2},

Comment: Same thing, null.

Comment: "Same thing, null" . then your problem is probably on the server code. make sure your PHP condition is true . inspect  the whole post data. `var_dump($_POST)`

Answer (score 1):

You code should work. But if I understood right - you trying to see post data just while entering page? If you do so - you'll see array(0) because when you open page - request is GET. You can see real post result via network debugger (dev tools etc.)

Comment: No. that is a legal syntax for defining object properties. it might be identifier, number , or string , [see](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects#Using_object_initializers)

Comment: Absolutely it can be. But, if this variable contains value then value will be used as is

Comment: I get the same thing. I noticed a weird thing. In the firebug console, when I check POST response, the var_dump appears ok:    array(1) { ["mbscr"]=>   string(1) "2" }    But what I see on the actual page is array(0) { }. Does this mean it's a server or client error? I'm not really that experienced. Thanks.

Comment: Show us please network console output for sent data and received data

Comment: How can i do that? The project is large, it has lots of GETs and just this one POST I'm trying to make. Should I use a print screen?

Comment: @AlexSlipknot . may be, but I always use the jquery ajax function as this `data:{name:name,age:age,salary:salary}` and it works just fine with me.

Comment: @Ciprian C Excuse me :) If I understood right - you trying to see post data just while entering page? If you do so - you'll see array(0) because when you open page - request is GET. You can see real post result via network debugger (dev tools etc.)

Comment: So does that mean that if i change POST to GET it should work? Because I've already tried that and I got the same results. Sorry, I am inexperienced.

Comment: @Accountant, oh, yeah, sorry. I didn't see braces {} so it is object. I'll correct answer

Comment: @Ciprian C, yes, you can check if post data exists on receiving data. For example you're already outputting it in console

Comment: @CiprianC Can you please explain that line "the var_dump appears ok: array(1) { ["mbscr"]=> string(1) "2" } But what I see on the actual page is array(0) { }. " `var_dump` should outputs to the *actual page*

Comment: When I use Firebug, in Network tab, if I click my POST and then select Response, there I get the right var_dump. On the page that I refresh, I get array(0).

Comment: POST data will be available only when you're accessing it. They are different requests. POST data does not store like SESSION

Comment: I changed it to GET and it still won't work. Is there no way I can make this work?

Comment: Hey, wait. Your data available only during request. So you can't see result when you're refreshing page.

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: I mean that post or get data variables available only on request. You can't see them when you're refreshing page (in your case)

Comment: Well, OK, thanks for all the help, I'll try to figure something out.